# what is this form of writing?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

What does it mean when a line is defined by two other lines in a system of equations:$$l_1: \begin{cases} x-y =1\\ x+z=2 \\ \end{cases}  $$

It makes no sense as a line should be defined by two planes..

Comment: The equation $x-y=1$ defines a plane, not a line. Same for the other equation...

Comment: The intersection of 2 planes is a line.

Answer (score 1):

As David mentioned in his comment, the equations represent two planes in 3D, not two lines:
$$x-y=1 \longleftrightarrow \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
x\in\mathbb{R}\\
y=x-1\\
z\in\mathbb{R}\\
\end{array} \right.
$$
$$x+z=2 \longleftrightarrow \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
x\in\mathbb{R}\\
y\in\mathbb{R}\\
z=2-x\\
\end{array} \right.
$$

However, when we restrict ourselves to OXY plane, the first equation describes in fact a line; so does the second on the OXZ plane.